# Remove vertical scroll bar from all pages except mat-select

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I added code to remove vertical scroll bar from the entire scope of the application. The code is below which I added to styles.css. But it has also removed scroll bars from the mat-select component, as a result my list of the dropdown is no more easily accessible. Please if someone can help me to understand how can I separate the mat-select from overall application style so that I can scroll my drop downs.

```
html {
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;  /* Remove scrollbar space */
  background: transparent;  /* Optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
  scrollbar-width: none;
}
```

Comment: You can simply add scrollbar to mat-select element?
This is CSS, you can "overwrite" previous changes by placing the code below your current code.

Answer (score 0):

That should do the trick... Use this class whenever you want to hide the scrollbar (not recommended btw, as some people don't use mouses...)

```
.noscrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar{display:none!important;visibility:hidden!important;}
```

gl.